# Насколько уместно употребление слова "касаемо" вместо слов "относительно", "по поводу"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

На мой взгляд, эта замена не оправдана. Звучит искусственно. Я воспринимаю это как отступление от нормы.

Answer (score 3):

**КАСАТЕЛЬНО**, предлог. кого-чего. **Книжн. и офиц**. Относительно кого-, чего-л. Быть осведомлённым к. всех обстоятельств дела.

**КАСАЕМО**, предлог. кого-чего. **Нар.-разг**. =Касательно. Кое-что касаемо прошлого я помню.

Нацкорпус: касаемо -  173, касательно -  1353.

**Эти предлоги используются в речи, но по словарю они не относятся к нейтральному стилю.**

В то же время удивляет то, что стилистическая принадлежность не всегда соблюдается. Возможно, эти слова в некоторых случаях имеют оттенок **иронии**, что характерно для смешения стилей,  но вот в деловых текстах и документах  слово ***касаемо*** не кажется уместным.

Примеры:

― **Касаемо** замужества твой прогноз чрезмерно мрачен, ― сказал Штрум. ― Ты похорошела за последнее время. [Василий Гроссман. Жизнь и судьба, ч. 1 (1960)]

А что **касаемо** средств, то первые шаги предприняты: уже есть спонсор, готовый вложить деньги в восстановление колокольни. [Елена Зиминова. Дом культуры и Дом веры (2013.04.19) // «Новгородские ведомости», 2013]

Теперь же тысячи новых, неясных мыслей, **касательно** одинокого положения их, зароились в моей голове, и мне стало так совестно, что мы богаты, а они бедны, что я покраснел и не мог решиться взглянуть на Катеньку. [Л. Н. Толстой. Отрочество (1854)]

Пожаловался на тесноту и закинул удочку **касательно** передачи музею первого этажа здания, где расположен промтоварный магазин. [Д. И. Саврасов. Про искателей алмазов (2003-2008)]

Comment: В том-то и дело, что  в большинстве случаев ирония отсутствует...

Comment: *А **что касаемо** средств...* Это уже явный перебор. Либо *что касается,* либо *касаемо,* но не *что касае**мо**.*

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, лучше говорить *"что касается". "Касаемо"* можно со скрипом принять как допустимый вариант, без которого *можно обойтись.* А вот *"что касаемо"* — это уж явно ошибочное употребление выражения *"что касается".*